# AngularJS: Is there a better way to achieve this than the one specified?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dry

I use a template that generates a Bootstrap tab layout. Like below:

```
<div class="a">
    <ul class="nav nav-bar nav-stacked" role="tabs">
        <li><a href="#home"></a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home">abc</div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Now this is pretty simple and straightforward tab navigation that can be hardcoded and achieved.

I have a dynamic `ng-repeat` on the `ul's` `li` and the tab-content's `div`s.

The JSON that I get from the REST service is something that contains the data for the tabs and the content to be displayed inside the tab-content within a single object. For eg:

```
{
    "0": "a": [{ // a- tab data
                   "0": "abc", // abc - data to be displayed inside the tab-content
                   "1": "xyz"
               }]
  ...
}
```

With such a JSON hierarchy, I basically need to ng-repeat twice. Once for the `ul li` and once for the tab-content as each object of the tab contains the data related to it.

So what I have done so far is:

```
<div class="a">
    <ul class="nav nav-bar nav-stacked" role="tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="foo in data"><a href="#home">{{foo.name}}</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" ng-repeat="foo in data">
            <p ng-repeat="f in foo.desc">{{f}}</p>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
So my question is, is there a smarter way to achieve this using a single `ng-repeat` rather than doing "foo in data" twice?

Sorry if my question isn't clear.

Comment: Can you not simply assign it twice after your JSON call? In your controller: `$scope.data=response; $scope.data2=response;` and second ng-repeat would be `foo in data2` - not ideal but an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-include` with `$templateCache` rather than `ng-repeat`. For example:

```js
var app = angular.module('foo', []);

function foo($templateCache)
  {
  var model = 
    {"data":
     [
       {"name": "Stack",
        "desc": ["Exchange", "Overflow"]
       }
     ]
    },
    cursor, i, bar = baz = "";
  
  for (i = 0; i < model.data.length; i++)
   {
    bar = bar.concat("<li>", model.data[i].name,"</li>");
    baz = baz.concat("<li>", model.data[i].desc.join().replace(/,/g,"</li><li>") );
    }
  
  $templateCache.put('name', bar);
  $templateCache.put('desc', baz);      
  }

app.run(foo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="foo">
  <ul ng-include="'name'"></ul>
  <ul ng-include="'desc'"></ul>
</div>
```

**References**

- [Tweak the Angular Test by Controlling the Template](http://www.randomjavascript.com/2015/06/tweak-angular-test-by-controlling.html)
- [AngularJS in a Groovy World](http://www.craigburke.com/angular-groovy-world/)
- [AngularJS Source: templateRequestSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/templateRequestSpec.js#L96)
- [AngularJS Source: ngIncludeSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/directive/ngIncludeSpec.js#L292)